# DatabaseManager has no default constructor

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hy Guys!

My problem is that Android is showing me an Error which says that I've no default constructor class. The Error occurs in the AndroidManifest.

Here is my Code:

```
package at.atn.android;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.SQLException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/at.atn.android/databases/";

public static String DB_NAME = "db.sqlite3";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 *
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.
```

}

Android Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/bus"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="at.atn.android.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="at.atn.android.PlanActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="at.atn.android.InfoActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="at.atn.android.PlanAusgabeSubActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="at.atn.android.SetzeZeitActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="at.atn.android.ListHaltestelleActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="at.atn.android.AktualisiereDB"></activity>
    <activity android:name="at.atn.android.DatabaseHelper"></activity>
</application>
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only declare activities with `activity` in your manifest. `DatabaseHelper` is not an activity and does not need to be declared in manifest. `AktualisiereDB` looks suspicious, too.

Just remove the non-activity activities from your manifest.